# Ad hoc deployment for an independent apple watch app

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, watchos, ad-hoc-distribution

I've built an independent apple watch app that I want to distribute to a few friends.
I don't want to go through the app store.

To get the app on my watch, I registered my iPhone and Apple Watch to my developer profile, connected my phone to my macbook, and then ran the app on my watch.

Is there another way to distribute an independent Apple Watch app?
Preferably a way they could download it from online somewhere.

Comment: “ To get the app on my watch, I registered my iPhone and Apple Watch to my developer profile, connected my phone to my macbook, and then ran the app on my watch.” That works temporarily. But not forever.

Comment: @matt Uh oh... I read somewhere that the profile would only work for a certain amount of days, but I put it on my watch to test and forgot about it. I guess it will be a cruel wake up call when it suddenly stops working.

Comment: Yup. Similarly you could use TestFlight as an easy distribution system, but you would have to re upload every 90 days. And so on.

Comment: @matt Darn. I guess every 90 days is the best I can do for the moment. I'm going to keep looking to see if there is a solution where I can upload it once and then not reupload again.

Comment: You would have to use an Apple sanctioned distribution method. Either the app store or an enterprise distribution. There is no other way to distribute a build that won't eventually expire. If you think about it, there's an obvious reason for that; if there were such a way, developers would do exactly what you're proposing to do, e.g. distribute to just friends and family.

Comment: Thanks @matt, you've cleared this up for me. While not ideal, I think testflight is the best approach for what I'm attempting to do. I'll do some research into how to use it for independent apple watch apps. Thanks :)